# React-apex-charts - area graph remove the "fill" color

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

[image]

I'm not entirely sure how to remove the color of the gaps between them, anyone know how to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Adding this option:

```
fill: {
    type: 'solid',
    colors: ['transparent'],
  },
```

made it work :)